# changing table column headings on click of button

Tags: jsp

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/pagedirectives.jsp"%>

<div style="background: #D6E8FF; padding: 10px;" class="advanced_search">
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/page.topmessagebox.jsp"%>

<table class="form" cellspacing="0" id="requestSubmissionEform">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><b>Label</b></td>
            <td class="label" align="left"><b>Form 1</b></td>
            <td class="label" align="left"><b>Form 2</b></td>
            <td class="label" align="left"><b>Form 3</b></td>
            <td class="label" align="left"><b>Form 4</b></td>
            <td class="label" align="left"><b>Form 5</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${eformDetailsList}" var="eformDetails"
            varStatus="status">

            <tr id="serviceTypeWithEform">
                <td class="label"><label for="${eformDetails.id}_0"><c:out
                    value="${eformDetails.label}" /></label> <input type="hidden"
                    id="label_${eformDetails.id}_0" value="${eformDetails.label}"
                    name="label_0"></input> <input type="hidden"
                    id="index_${eformDetails.id}_0" value="${eformDetails.id}"
                    name="index_0"></input></td>
                <c:if test="${eformDetails.controlType==1}">
                    <td id="Col0" style="visibility: visible;"><input
                        id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_0" class="eformDetail"
                        type="text" value="" name="form_0"></input></td>
                    <td id="Col1" style="visibility: visible;"><input
                        id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_1" class="eformDetail"
                        type="text" value="" name="form_1"></input></td>
                    <td id="Col2" style="visibility: visible;"><input
                        id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_2" class="eformDetail"
                        type="text" value="" name="form_2"></input></td>
                    <td id="Col3" style="visibility: visible;"><input
                        id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_3" class="eformDetail"
                        type="text" value="" name="form_3"></input></td>
                    <td id="Col4" style="visibility: visible;"><input
                        id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_4" class="eformDetail"
                        type="text" value="" name="form_4"></input></td>
                </c:if>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${empty eformDetailsList}">
            <tr id="serviceTypeWithNoEform">
                <td><b>There is no eform associated with this Service Type</b></td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

this page will have 2 buttons (prev. and next). on click of next i want to change column headings to form 6,7,8,9,10 and so on for further clicks. please help!

Comment: the code din get posted. basically i have a form with textboxes, 5 columns. the columns have headings as form 1, form 2, etc.. this page will have 2 buttons (prev. and next). On click of next i want to change column headings to form 6,7,8,9,10 and so on for further clicks. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print them dynamically depending on the current page, starting with page index 0. On every *next* button press increment the page index by 1.

```
<tr>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Form ${(page * 5) + 1}</th>
    <th>Form ${(page * 5) + 2}</th>
    <th>Form ${(page * 5) + 3}</th>
    <th>Form ${(page * 5) + 4}</th>
    <th>Form ${(page * 5) + 5}</th>
</tr>
```

*(please note that table header cells are to be represented by `<th>`, not by `<td>`)*